# get the last digit from the name

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

i want to know if i can get the last digit of the input, but if the last one is 0 i want it to ignore it and take the one before it... like bob120, last digit is 20 not 0, to make it the level for the person

here is my code and i tried for 2 days to know how but i'm stuck with this problem.
and i tried %10 but still it's the same problem.

```
number = number.substring(5,6);
level = Integer.parseInt(number);
```

I'm using scanner package

thank you in advance

Comment: The last digit cannot be 20. 20 is a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the input is a String and you like the use substring the code will be

```
int pos= number.lenght();
String lastChar = number.substring(pos-1,pos);
```

Note: number is a String : )...

Then you are right on the `Integer.parseInt()`, be aware of error if its not a number (try, catch)...

Then you need a if statement...change your pos and try again....

To do this task it would be better to use the `String.toCharArray()` at loop it backwards... so if you have time study this..

Something like this:

```
public int getLastNumDifThenZero(String text){
    char[] ca = text.toCharArray();
    for (int i = ca.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        char a = ca[i];
        try {
            int n = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(a));
            if (n!=0){
                return n;
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            //Not a number
        }

    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: similar to looping backwards and using charAt(idx)

Answer (score 0):

You can loop from the end of String and search for 'non-zero' value (result char is String) :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // example returns 7
        String num = "85677000";
        char lastDigit =' ';

        // looping from end and searching non zero digit
        for(int i=num.length()-1 ; i>=0 ;i--){
            lastDigit=num.charAt(i);
            if (lastDigit != '0'){
                System.out.println(lastDigit);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```